# How to eliminate all grouped records based on failed criteria on one record

Tags: sql-server

I have a recurring problem of needing queries that don't just eliminate one record that doesn't meet a criteria but eliminates all records based on some other grouping. For example, for a table with the following:

```
Name     ProdType   Prod   Spoiled     DateReceived  
Jack     Fruit      Apple   N          1/1/2019
Jack     Fruit      Pear    Y          1/1/2018
Jack     Fruit      Orange  N          1/1/2019
Jack     Vegetable  Okra    N          1/1/2019
Jack     Vegetable  Squash  N          1/1/2018
Jill     Fruit      Apple   N          4/1/2019
Jill     Fruit      Cherry  N          4/1/2019
Jill     Vegetable  Corn    Y          4/1/2019
Jill     Vegetable  Okra    N          4/1/2019
```

my query might be to search for who had what fruit where none of the fruit was spoiled.

So far I've been using nested select statements, but as I add criteria, it's getting more difficult.

```
SELECT NAME
    ,PRODTYPE
    ,PROD
    ,SPOILED
    ,DATEREC
FROM inventory
WHERE NAME in (
    SELECT DISTINCT Name from (SELECT Name FROM inventory
                WHERE ProdType = 'fruit' as Data)

    WHERE Name NOT IN (SELECT Name from inventory WHERE Name in (
            SELECT Name 
            WHERE Spoiled = 'Y'))
    )
```

In the example with Jack and Jill, my query would return 2 results for Jill (1 for each fruit) and none for Jack.

Usually at least two tables are involved. I'm running into problems (usually no results or I can't even get past errors to run the query) when I add criteria, such as it's OK if it's spoiled if it was received before X date, and also when adding additional tables.

Is this way of nesting selects to create lists to then search the best way or does SQL offer something better?

Thanks.

Comment: please add expected output

Comment: What would your desired result be for the sample data?

Comment: Sorry, it was buried in my question, but I expected the results to be 2 records for Jill for each of the 2 fruits she had since neither was spoiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With NOT EXISTS:

```
select i.* 
from inventory i
where 
  i.prodtype = 'Fruit' and
  not exists (
    select 1 from inventory
    where name = i.name and
    prodtype = 'Fruit' and
    spoiled = 'Y'
  )
```

Comment: you need to correlate `Prod` as well I think

Comment: Why? All the rows of type 'Fruit' will be returned.

Comment: yep on second read I don't think you do. I thought the intention was to return rows where there wasn't a spoiled fruit of that type for that person. But that isn't correct

Comment: I am so excited to try this. I'll let you know what happens.

Answer (score 1):

There are many creative ways to express a query in SQL. Your example could also be realized this way, for example:

```
SELECT
    name,
    prodtype,
    prod,
    spoiled,
    daterec
FROM
    inventory
WHERE
    prodtype = 'Fruit' AND
    name NOT IN (SELECT name
                 FROM inventory
                 WHERE prodtype = 'Fruit' AND spoiled = 'Y')
```

To determine the right (or at least an acceptable) way to go requires a lot of exercise. And there often is no "standard" solution to a certain data request. There will be scenarios where you completely need to redesign/rewrite your queries if a single requirement changes which does not fit in the existing query structure.